# When to use text/plain instead of text/html?

Tags: html, ajax, text, httprequest, content-type

When is it recommended to use `text/plain` content type over `text/html`.

Imagine I'm developing an endpoint which is consumed in an async manner (ajax) and only returns a string. Am I supposed to use the `text/plain` content type in this case?

Is it safe to say that `text/html` should only be used if the response body contains HTML tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With text/plain, you can only send text file content

With text/HTML you can send HTML file content, allowing markup formatting

It's that simple...

Don't overthink it, it's quite self explantory

Text:

> <b>some bold text</b>

HTML:

> **some bold text**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to render the string returned by API in browser as it is then you can use `text/plain`. Else If you want browser to render you content as html then use `text/html`.

For Example, if `<b>Hi there</b>`is returned from API.

So `text/plain` will print `<b>Hi there</b>`, but `text/html` will print **Hi There**.